# How do I create a new Firebird database from the command line?

Tags: command-line, firebird, isql

I'd like to create a new Firebird database in my C# client application. Is there a command line utility that lets you do this?

Comment: client application is made with  ?

Comment: The client application is built in C#. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use [isql](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/isql_fb) but I advice you to use directly the api.

```
isql -input test.sql
```

test.sql is like this :

```
SET SQL DIALECT 3;

SET NAMES UNICODE_FSS;

CREATE DATABASE 'D:\testdata.fdb'
USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey'
PAGE_SIZE 16384
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
    CUST_ID       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CUST_NAME     INTEGER,
    CUST_UNISITE  INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE SMS_DETAIL (
    SD_ID                       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SD_MESSAGE_DATA             VARCHAR(160)
);
```

creating database via the [api](http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&l=;KNOWLEDGEBASE;ID=%2752%27)

Comment: Thanks for the isql example. How would I use the API? What language is the API written in?

Comment: the API language is C++. Many components encapsulate the API in different language. I think you can make this with the dotnet provider.

Answer (score 0):

We are using something like this for keys insensitive. (Firebird 3 >)

```
isql -input test.sql

SET SQL DIALECT 3;

SQL> create database 'c:\database\test.fdb' page_size 8192 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8
CON> ;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (

    CUST_ID       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CUST_NAME     VARCHAR(20) COLATE UNICODE_CI,
    CUST_UNISITE  INTEGER
);
```